# C++ code doesn't compile correctly after adding output file

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, output

I have already completed most of my assignment which requires the use of three functions that I have up and running correctly so far. The problem is when I add the respective code to output to a file the last function does not return a value and the value I want to be output to the file is not written to the file. Also the process ends with return -1. Please take a look at the code below and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string* returnGreetings() {

    int const SIZE = 50000;
    string message;
    string* greetings = new string[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {

    if (i < 12500)
        {
            message = "Hi";
            greetings[i] = message;
        }
    else if (i >= 12500 && i < 25000)
        {
            message = "Hey";
            greetings[i] = message;
        }
    else if (i >= 25000 && i < 37500)
        {
            message = "Hello";
            greetings[i] = message;
        }
    else if (i >= 37500)
        {
            message = "What's up";
            greetings[i] = message;
        }
    }
    return greetings;
}

vector<string> returnVectorGreetings()
{
    string message;
    vector <string> greetings;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {

    if (i < 12500)
        {
            message = "Hi";
            greetings.push_back(message);
        }
    else if (i >= 12500 && i < 25000)
        {
            message = "Hey";
            greetings.push_back(message);
        }
    else if (i >= 25000 && i < 37500)
        {
            message = "Hello";
            greetings.push_back(message);
        }
    else if (i >= 37500)
        {
            message = "What's up";
            greetings.push_back(message);
        }
    }


    return greetings;
}

int addTen(int *numberAddress)
{
    return *numberAddress + 10;
}

int main()
{

    int *numberAddress;

    string* address = returnGreetings();

    cout << address;

    string *a = returnGreetings();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) cout << a[i] << endl;

    vector<string> m = returnVectorGreetings();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) cout << m[i] << endl;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";

    cin >> *numberAddress;

    cout << "The number plus 10 is: " << addTen(numberAddress) << endl;

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("output.txt");
    outfile << address;
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've never initialized `numberAddress`.

Comment: @Barmar Even if I do still doesn't work

Comment: You're writing a pointer to the file, not the contents of the array.

Comment: What did open() return??? and u r writing pointer into the file as mentioned above

Comment: @Saran-san What I want is to write the address of the array to the file. When I call the last function "addTen" and I don't open or initialize the file everything works fine. If I initialize the file and open it the last function won't work. I think is the combination of the me calling the function "addTen" and outputting to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this 
    int *numberAddress = new int;

instead of 
      int *numberAddress;

You need to allocate the memory for a pointer before you use that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `numberAddress`.  It's not initialized.

When you try to use it with cin and pass it to `addTen()`, your program is probably accessing invalid memory and crashing.

Try initializing it to point to an int variable, like this:

```
int naValue;
int *numberAddress = &naValue; // initialize numberAddress
```

Comment: This is what Im trying to accomplish with the function I have written "Create a function that takes in a pointer to an integer. Send in the address of the integer. Add ten to the integer using the pointer within the function."

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that requirement.  For which case, you can initialize int *numberAddress to point to an integer.  `int *numberAddress = &i;`

Comment: You're welcome.  I should point out that if you use `new`, you should always use `delete` when you are finished with the memory, or you will leak memory.  This may be important to your instructor.